# How to add time stamp with pdfbox and TimeStampToken

Tags: timestamp, pdf-generation, pdfbox, trusted-timestamp

I want to add time stamp to file from third party time server.
When pdf is open in acrobat or other pdf viewer I want to see information about time stamp in signatures card or any other. Additionally I want to visualize time stamp graphically as image or text in pdf with time stamp.

I get token from time server:

```
import org.bouncycastle.tsp.TimeStampResponse;
import org.bouncycastle.tsp.TimeStampToken;

...

public TimeStampToken getTimeStampToken(){

  ...

  return response.getTimeStampToken();
}
```

Now how to add time stamp to pdf using pdf box?

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.PDSignature;

...

public static void addTimeStamp(final File pdfFile, final File signedPdfFile, TimeStampToken token) {

    try (
        FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(pdfFile);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(signedPdfFile);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(signedPdfFile);
        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(pdfFile)) {
        int readCount;
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
        while ((readCount = fis1.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, readCount);
        }

        final PDSignature signature = new PDSignature();
        signature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE);
        signature.setSubFilter(PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
        signature.setName("NAME");
        signature.setLocation("LOCATION");
        signature.setReason("REASON");
        signature.setSignDate(Calendar.getInstance());

        doc.addSignature(signature);
        doc.saveIncremental(fos);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: The signing sample code does has this already, with the exception of "graphically as image or text in pdf". Did you see it?

Answer (score 1):

*As you just mention a time stamp, not a signature with a signature time stamp, I assume you mean a document time stamp as per PAdES LTV or PDF-2.*

The PDFBox signing examples have been implemented with regular digital signatures in mind, not naked digital time stamps. But you can adapt them fairly easily. [CreateVisibleSignature](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/CreateVisibleSignature.java) and other examples create the signature bytes to embed in the `SignatureInterface` method `sign` implemented in the parent class `CreateSignatureBase`:

```
/**
 * SignatureInterface implementation.
 *
 * This method will be called from inside of the pdfbox and create the PKCS #7 signature.
 * The given InputStream contains the bytes that are given by the byte range.
 *
 * This method is for internal use only.
 *
 * Use your favorite cryptographic library to implement PKCS #7 signature creation.
 */
@Override
public byte[] sign(InputStream content) throws IOException
{
    //TODO this method should be private
    try
    {
        List<Certificate> certList = new ArrayList<Certificate>();
        certList.add(certificate);
        Store certs = new JcaCertStore(certList);
        CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
        org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Certificate cert = org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Certificate.getInstance(ASN1Primitive.fromByteArray(certificate.getEncoded()));
        ContentSigner sha1Signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256WithRSA").build(privateKey);
        gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().build()).build(sha1Signer, new X509CertificateHolder(cert)));
        gen.addCertificates(certs);
        CMSProcessableInputStream msg = new CMSProcessableInputStream(content);
        CMSSignedData signedData = gen.generate(msg, false);
        if (tsaClient != null)
        {
            signedData = signTimeStamps(signedData);
        }
        return signedData.getEncoded();
    }
    catch (GeneralSecurityException e)
    {
        throw new IOException(e);
    }
    catch (CMSException e)
    {
        throw new IOException(e);
    }
    catch (TSPException e)
    {
        throw new IOException(e);
    }
    catch (OperatorCreationException e)
    {
        throw new IOException(e);
    }
}
```

*([CreateSignatureBase](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/CreateSignatureBase.java))*

(BTW, I strongly disagree with the TODO-comment.)

Furthermore, `CreateVisibleSignature` sets the subfilter of the signature in `signPDF`:

```
/**
 * Sign pdf file and create new file that ends with "_signed.pdf".
 *
 * @param inputFile The source pdf document file.
 * @param signedFile The file to be signed.
 * @param tsaClient optional TSA client
 * @param signatureFieldName optional name of an existing (unsigned) signature field
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void signPDF(File inputFile, File signedFile, TSAClient tsaClient, String signatureFieldName) throws IOException
{
    [...]

    PDSignature signature;

    // sign a PDF with an existing empty signature, as created by the CreateEmptySignatureForm example. 
    signature = findExistingSignature(doc, signatureFieldName);

    if (signature == null)
    {
        // create signature dictionary
        signature = new PDSignature();
    }

    // default filter
    signature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE);

    // subfilter for basic and PAdES Part 2 signatures
    signature.setSubFilter(PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);

    [...]
}
```

To create a PAdES document time stamp, you can simply create a copy of the `CreateVisibleSignature` example, override the `SignatureInterface` method `sign` with an implementation that returns a time stamp token for the data in the given `InputStream`, replace the line

```
    signature.setSubFilter(PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
```

in `signPDF` with

```
    signature.setSubFilter(new COSName("ETSI.RFC3161"));
```

and add a line

```
    signature.setType(new COSName("DocTimeStamp"));
```

to set the type to time stamp.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add time stamp to pdf without keystore certs and keys and it looks like this:

```
public static void signWithTimeStampToken() throws InvalidPasswordException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, TSPException {
    final File inFile = new File("test.pdf");
    final File outFile = new File("test_signed.pdf");
    final MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    final TSAClient tsaClient = new TSAClient(new URL("your service"), null, null, digest);
    PdfTimeStampUtils.signPdf(inFile, outFile, tsaClient);
}

private static void signPdf(final File inFile, final File outFile, final TSAClient tsaClient) throws InvalidPasswordException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        TSPException {
    final PDSignature signature = new PDSignature();
    signature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE);
    signature.setSubFilter(COSName.getPDFName("ETSI.RFC3161"));
    signature.setSignDate(Calendar.getInstance());
    final PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(inFile);

    final TimestampSignatureImpl sig = new TimestampSignatureImpl(tsaClient);
    pdf.addSignature(signature, sig);
    pdf.saveIncremental(new FileOutputStream(outFile));
    pdf.close();
}
```

I am using tsaclient from pdfbox examples [TSAClient](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/TSAClient.java)

When I open signed pdf in acrobat I can see in signatures:

[image]

Comment: In your question you said you *want to visualize time stamp graphically*; usually by this one means an in-content visualization, not the entry on the signature panel. Did I misunderstand you or have you simply dropped that requirement?

Comment: What I meant is to have ability to add something (custom image or text) to distinguish signed and unsigned without viewing signature like in attached image. But it is only additional ( I am curious ) and my answer does not contain it at all. I placed it because i figured it out how to add time stamp.